# This is curious, when we start a new multi-process, can't we use another method of the same class?

Tags: python, multiprocess

My goal is to create a new process every time the class is instantiated in an object, I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.

I use an API from IQ Option, but it only allows the connection of only one user, among several attempts, I discovered that with Multi-process, I can connect more than one account to the API.

But when creating a new process in `__init__()` I can't use the other methods of the class, because I get the message that the self.API is not an attribute of my class, I'll be leaving the example code below and also the exact error that the debugger sent, thank you very much and god bless you all.

```
from time import sleep
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
import multiprocessing

class Instance_New_User:

    def __init__(self,email,password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        
        multiprocessing.Process(target=self.connect).start()
    
    def connect(self):
    
        self.API = IQ_Option(self.email,self.password)
        self.API.connect()
        
        if self.API.check_connect() == False:
            print('Failed to connect')
        if self.API.check_connect() == True:
            print('Connected')
            
    def get_balance(self):
        return self.API.get_balance()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    email = str(input('Put here your email of IQ Option:'))
    password = str(input('Put here your password of IQ Option:'))
    
    var =  Instance_New_User(email,password)
    
    print(var.get_balance()) <- I want to use a method of a class

ERROR : AttributeError: 'Instance_New_User' object has no attribute 'API'
```

My goal is to create a new process every time the class is instantiated in an object, I don't know if I'm doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiprocessing the wrong way.

When you use `multiprocessing.Process(....).start()`, you are literally starting a new process with a new address space. That process gets *copies* of the objects that you use to start it.  So your main thread doesn't see any changes you make to `self` in the sub-thread, and vice versa.  Hence `self.API` doesn't exist.

To talk to a thread, you need to set up some sort of communication channel.  You would send a message to the thread "Please tell me the balance", and the thread, would call self.API..... and report the result back.   You main thread has no access to the connection except by asking the subprocess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, could you tell me, how can I create a new process every time the class is instantiated?

Comment: You are starting a new process correctly.  You are just talking to it incorrectly.